# McLean theorem for Fano varieties?

Tags: kahler-manifolds, fano-varieties, lagrangian-submanifolds

Well-known McLean theorem states that deformations of special Lagrangian $L$ submanifolds in Calabi-Yau manifold are unobstructed and in bijection with harmonic 1-forms on $L$. The proof relies on the holomorphic calibration, which is not available for Fano varieties. My question is: is there any similar result for local deformations of minimal Lagrangians in Fano variety  $X$ (by minimality I mean that Riemannian volume is stationary under deformations by arbitrary normal vector fields)?

The obvious analogue is not quite true. For instance, MLAGs in $S^2$ are big circles and thus the deformation space has real dimension 2 while $b^1(S^1)=1$.

In 'Minimal Lagrangian tori in Kahler-Einstein manifolds', Prof. Goldstein constructs a bijection between MLAGs in $X$ and conic SLAGs in the total space of the canonical bundle of $X$. Thus, deformation theory of MLAGs can be related to that of SLAGs but one has to preserve the conic condition. On the other hand, not all Fano varieties admit Kahler-Einstein metric.

In 'The Novikov-Veselov hierarchy of equations and integrable deformations of minimal Lagrangian tori in $\mathbb{C}P^2$', Prof. Mironov describes certain deformations of MLAG tori in $\mathbb{C}P^2$ arising from Novikov-Veselov hierarchy. Probably, not every deformation is realized by this construction.

In 'Special Lagrangian cones in $\mathbb{C}^3$ and primitive harmonic maps', Prof. McIntosh has obtained an algebro-geometric description of the moduli space of MLAGs in $\mathbb{C}P^2$ but the spectral curve construction is rather indirect so I am not sure that it leads to usable description of local deformations.